# Insert en SQL Error al hacer query

Tags: sql, insert

Amigos no veo mi error alguien podría sacarme de mi ignoracia?

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; it seems the error is around: 'INSERT INTO USERS_ ( username, name, lastnameP, lastnameM, ' at line 24

```
CREATE TABLE USERS_(
  id INT(50) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  created_at TIMESTAMP(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
  username VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  lastnameP VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  lastnameM VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  pass VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL,
  mail varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  admin BOOLEAN NULL,
  user BOOLEAN NULL,
  owner BOOLEAN NULL,
  gender INT(1) NULL,
  datenac DATE NOT NULL,
  phone VARCHAR(20) NULL,
  calle VARCHAR(200) NULL,
  colonia VARCHAR(200) NULL,
  estado VARCHAR(200) NULL,
  cp INT(6) NULL,
  img VARCHAR(500) NULL,
  id_usercreated INT(20) NOT NULL,
  status VARCHAR(50) NULL
);
INSERT INTO
  USERS_ (
    username,
    name,
    lastnameP,
    lastnameM,
    pass,
    mail,
    admin,
    user,
    owner,
    gender,
    datenac,
    phone,
    id_usercreated
  )
VALUES
  (
    "tuname",
    "tes1t",
    "est",
    "tes2",
    "pass",
    "admin@ad.com",
    true,
    false,
    false,
    1,
    CURDATE(),
    12345678,
    1
  );
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Qué motor de base de datos estás usando?

Comment: ¿Cuál sería tu línea 24?

Answer (score 1):

El campo phone es Varchar y en el INSERT lo colocas como un número, debes escribirlo entre comillas.

Coloca todo el error la próxima vez así es más fácil verlo :-)

Comment: no eso no era... agregué las comillas y el error persiste, ese es TODO el error que me genera. Lo estoy provando aquí y me da lo mismo https://www.eversql.com/sql-syntax-check-validator/

Comment: Aummm esta raro usualmente dice la columna también, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ac6a31/1 fijate allí, así como colocaste en la descripción del problema lo probé (primero le das a build y luego abajo a ejecutar) . Solo cambie eso que te comenté. Comentame que tal te fue.

Comment: En la página que comentas si coloco tu query así tal cual me dice 100% a ti te indica que esta mal? Me dice: "Great work, the query's syntax is valid!"

Comment: si deja subo una imagen de lo que manda cuando le doy mi mismo query

Comment: Ya vi mejor la cosa en un principio pensé que la página no válidaba nada que no fuese querys o consultas, creo que es que no te deja validar más de uno a la vez. Coloca primero el create válidas y luego válida el insert y te dice que estan bien los dos.

Comment: ok ya vi que es verdad,pero porque será que no puedo correr ambos a la vez?

Comment: Porque esa herramientas debe estar diseñada para verificar un solo query a la vez o exige alguna manera de indicarle que será más de un query. Tendrías que buscar en la página si en algún apartado hablan de eso.

Answer (score 1):

Corre cada consulta por separado. Cada consulta termina con el punto y coma `;`. Es decir, primero creas y luego insertas.

Otra opción que puedes hacer es crear un *stored procedure*.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE crear_insertar()
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS USERS_(
  id INT(50) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  created_at TIMESTAMP(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
  username VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  lastnameP VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  lastnameM VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  pass VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL,
  mail varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  admin BOOLEAN NULL,
  user BOOLEAN NULL,
  owner BOOLEAN NULL,
  gender INT(1) NULL,
  datenac DATE NOT NULL,
  phone VARCHAR(20) NULL,
  calle VARCHAR(200) NULL,
  colonia VARCHAR(200) NULL,
  estado VARCHAR(200) NULL,
  cp INT(6) NULL,
  img VARCHAR(500) NULL,
  id_usercreated INT(20) NOT NULL,
  status VARCHAR(50) NULL
);
INSERT INTO  USERS_ (
    username,
    name,
    lastnameP,
    lastnameM,
    pass,
    mail,
    admin,
    user,
    owner,
    gender,
    datenac,
    phone,
    id_usercreated
  )
VALUES (
    "tuname",
    "tes1t",
    "est",
    "tes2",
    "pass",
    "admin@ad.com",
    true,
    false,
    false,
    1,
    CURDATE(),
    12345678,
    1
);
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Y después la llamas con `CALL`.

```
CALL crear_insertar();
```

Eso es en el caso de que quieras tener alguna manera de correr dos consultas "al mismo tiempo" o, literalmente, con una llamada.